# I am not able to scroll to elements below the list view. How to view those

Tags: android, listview, scrollview, horizontalscrollview

I am using a ScrollView inside which I am using RelativeLayout inside which I am using ListView inside HorizontalScrollView. Now after that i am placing a button but not able to scroll to that button as the page is not scrolling, just the ListView is scrolling.

I want the list to scroll and after the list is finished the page should scroll so that i can see the button to click it

how to do that

I am sharing my xml that I have made so far

### main.xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

<RelativeLayout
   
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/heading2"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Horizontal List View"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:focusable="true"/>



    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="370dp"
        android:id="@+id/hori_scroll_view"
        android:layout_below="@+id/heading2"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/list"/>

    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <Button

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/page2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/hori_scroll_view"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Next" />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: why you put List view inside HorizontalScrollView? Just playing with layouts ?

Comment: I am having a lot of columns in my ListView thats why it is a must to use HorizontalScrollView

Comment: Then You have to put this button outside scrollview. Thats the only possible solution . I think you do not need the top scrollview in that scenario lust use  Relative layout as roo container . Got the point ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with RecyclerView

```
<ScrollView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/heading2"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Horizontal List View"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:focusable="true"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="370dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/heading2"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/list"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/page2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/list"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Next" />
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Then Add this in your Activity,

```
LinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        RecyclerView myList = findViewById(R.id.list);
        myList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to scroll horizontally/ vertically with list view. If you are trying to scroll vertically you have to use [NestedScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html) and [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) with in it.